# Equivalence of Lie groupoids $\phi: H \rightarrow G$ induces an equivalence of categories $\phi^*: G\text{-spaces} \rightarrow H\text{-spaces}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, groupoids, orbifolds, lie-groupoids

In [Orbifolds as Groupoids](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0203100) there is the notion of an equivalence $\phi: H \rightarrow G$ between Lie groupoids (2.4) and of $G$-spaces (5.1).

Given a smooth functor $\phi: H \rightarrow G$ we can obtain a functor
$$
\phi^*: G\text{-spaces} \rightarrow H\text{-spaces}
$$
which sends a $G$-space $E$ with anchor $\pi:E \rightarrow G_0$ to the $H$-space $E \mathbin{_\pi \times_{\phi_0}} H_0$ with the induced action.

I'm trying to prove the following, stated in section 5.1:

> If $\phi$ is an equivalence (2.4) then this functor $\phi^*$ is an equivalence of categories.

I'm struggling to come up with an inverse functor, that is given a $H$-space $F$ I need to find a $G$-space $E$ such that $\phi^*E$ is isomorphic to $F$.

Let $\pi: F \rightarrow H_0$ be the anchor map. My first attempt was to try to turn $F$ into an $E$-space with anchor map $\phi_0 \circ \pi$, but then there is no clear way to give $F$ a $G$-action.

My next thought was some sort of fibre product of $F$ with $G_0$ or $G_1$, allowing us to act by an element of $G_1$. Or even a product involving $H$ to make use of the following diffeomorphism in the definition of an equivalence:
$$
H_1 \rightarrow (H_0 \times H_0) \times_{G_0 \times G_0} G_1, \quad h \mapsto (s(h), t(h), \phi_1(h)).
$$
Basically I've tried lots of things and nothing has come out. Maybe the proof is more abstract and a direct construction isn't obvious.

I'd appreciate any hints or solutions anyone can offer!

Comment: Often it's easier to show that a functor is fully faithful and essentially surjective (because instead of trying to do everything at once by finding the inverse, you can separate the argument in three parts). Have you tried that?

Comment: Hi Najib. Yes I did try that, I think faithfulness works out easy enough but the other two are tricky. Essential surjectivity still requires you to obtain a reasonable G-space from a H-space, so I run into the same problem as finding an inverse functor.

Comment: If $\phi$ is an equivalence, can't you get a quasi-inverse ?  And use that to get a quasi-inverse of $\phi^*$ (ah no, ok, I hadn't seen the definition of equivalence of smooth groupoids)

Comment: I'm no expert on Lie groupoids but surely there is a notion of $2$-cells between parallel arrows such that (assuming some form of choice) equivalences in the sense of Moerdijk's notes are equivalences in a 2-categorical sense? Then I would go through Max's route: prove that the contravariant mapping $G\mapsto G\text{-spaces}, \phi \mapsto \phi^\ast$ is actually a pseudo-functor and you're done.

Comment: Moerdijk's equivalence is basically a smooth formulation of an equivalence of categories, so we can get an inverse functor. I think the problem is that this functor doesn't need to be smooth, so the functor on $G$ or $H$-spaces might not be well defined? (I hope I interpreted your comment correctly)